# how can I use 2 database in if else statement jsp?

Tags: mysql, jsp

For my program I want to have a successful login for user and admin with my code below. How could i use 2 different database one for user and one for admin in if else statement. Here below is my code.

```
 <%@page import="DAO.LoginDao"%>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
    <%@ page import="javax.sql.*"%>
        <jsp:useBean id="l" class="table.javabeans"></jsp:useBean>
        <jsp:setProperty property="*" name="l"/>


        <% String user = request.getParameter("username");
            String pass = request.getParameter("password");
            String rad = request.getParameter("User");%>

        <% 
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database","root","cdjade2012");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs;
            rs = st.executeQuery("select * from register where username = '"+user+"'");
            if(rs.next()){
                if(rs.getString(4).equals(pass)){
                    if(rad.equals("Users")){
                    out.println("welcome" + user);
                    String redirectURL = "User.jsp";
                    response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
                    }
                }       
                else{
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database","root","cdjade2012");
            Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rse;
            rse = sta.executeQuery("select * from admin where useradmin = '"+user2+"'");
            if(rse.next()){
                if(rse.getString(2).equals(pass2)){
                    if(rad2.equals("Admin")){
                    out.println("welcome" + user2);
                    String send = "Admin.jsp";
                    response.sendRedirect(send);
                    }
                }       
                else{
                    out.println("Invalid Password!");
                }

            }
                }

            }
                else{
                    response.sendRedirect("admin_login.jsp");

            }
            %>
```

The problem with this code is that when i enter the database for the admin it can't get the data. The location where lies the problem is in the code of else where i put another database but for the 1st database, user database it goes successfully not a single problem and it works fine.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Just from looking at your connection strings - it's the same database, no need to use 2 connections.

Comment: When I run it the only thing that runs in my login page is the button for user what should I do for it to read the admins database ?